# How can I transfer ownership of a file in Google Drive that isn't part of Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I'm trying to find a way to transfer ownership of a file in Google Drive to another user. I can share a file with another user, but I can't find a way to transfer ownership of the file. There seem to be solutions out there for Google Docs, Sheets and Slides, but not for normal files like `.mp4` or `.mov`.

Ownership of the file matters for a few reasons, one of them being that the file is counted against the quota of the owner of the file.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this, but I have found a workaround. Let's say A wants to transfer ownership of a file to B.

1. A shares the file with B.
2. B logs in, and makes a copy of the file by right-clicking on the file, and clicking "make a copy".
3. A or B can now delete the original file.
4. The new file can be renamed to be the same name as the original file. The new file also needs to be shared with A.

Any links to the old file will not point to the new file, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The method of cross-domain transfer with preserving file IDs using Google Shared Folders is well described [here](https://www.tabgeeks.com/tabgeeks-blog/how-to-transfer-ownership-between-domains-in-google-drive).

Summary:

1. Setup Google Shared Drive.
2. Neutralize ownership in Shared Drive.
3. Assign new ownership.

If you do not have access to Google Workspace (former G Suite), you can use my utility published on the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/transfer_files_ownership/631873519917) and also available [here](https://movefiles.app) as a web application.

Comment: Thanks. Could you describe the process in the answer post? That way, if the link breaks, the answer post is still useful.

Comment: It looks like this solution is only available for those with a paid plan for Google Workspace (or on a free trial of a paid plan).

Comment: >It looks like this solution is only available for those with a paid plan for Google Workspace (or on a free trial of a paid plan)<br/>
In my solution, I hide all this stuff from the user. So it's suitable for both Workspace and free users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).