# How to transfer Google Docs from GSuite to a personal gmail account?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I'd like to transfer all my docs from a GSuite (used to be called Google Apps) account to a personal google one.

I see plenty of examples of how to move documents [between GSuite accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13517/transfer-google-docs-from-one-account-to-another), or how to move personal documents to GSuite.  I am not seeing a way to move data from a GSuite account to a personal.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer Google Docs from one account to another](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13517/transfer-google-docs-from-one-account-to-another)

Comment: Transfer between domains that aren't part of the same organization is the same than transfer from a G Suite account to a "personal" account (we could say that the domain for personal accounts is gmail.com) . In a technical sense it's not possible but you can make a copy of the files.

Comment: @Rubén In my question I mentioned this link.  It doesn't work for the task I want.